# Log shipping on secondary server

Tags: sql-server, transaction-log, log-shipping

Log shipping fails with the below error. Sql agent on secondary server has access to the folder and files in security. It is not a firewall issue. I created the jobs using the LS scripts as it fails through GUI.

I have done it before on a different server where there were several LS databases. This is a new primary and secondary server and not sure what I am missing. Thanks for the help

```
***** Error: Access to the path '\\sqlp\R$\MSSQL10_50.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Backup\Database' is denied.(mscorlib) ***
----- END OF TRANSACTION LOG COPY     -----**
```

Comment: The `R$` share is only accessible by administrators.  Therein lies your problem, with almost 100% certainty.  You should create a share on the `Backup` folder with security that allows the SQL Server service account write access.

Comment: Yes that was it. I gave sa account admin rights on the server. Thank you for your help and time!

Answer (score 1):

I've ran into this same problem! As Mr. Vernon stated, the account needs admin access to the server.  However, that is not the recommended way of providing access to the service account, especially if you're to follow the "least privilege" security mantra.

Instead, perform the following:

- Create an appropriately named security group
- Add the SQL Server Agent account to the group
- Create a shared folder on the server you're shipping the logs to
- Assign the newly created security group with Modify permissions to the folder